# Identify this metal slider bracket?

Tags: furniture, self-assembly-furniture

I am doing a DIY project at home and came across this sliding metal bracket and plastic plate assembly. I have no idea where it came from but I think probably IKEA, although it could be anywhere. But it seems to actually do exactly what I need - that is if I could figure out how to mount it.

I have been puzzling over this for an hour with no instructions but I cannot figure out how the metal part clamps to the plastic part, and I don't have any instructions. I have also been googling things like "metal sliding bracket", "metal keyboard sliding bracket", throwing in works like "IKEA" but I cannot find this precise part.

I don't know if I am missing another piece which holds it all together. Can anybody identify this thing so I can find an assembly guide or something?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is the size of it

Comment: Can you tell of any way of the plastic and metal pieces fit together?  Screw holes matching up, or posts/holes fitting together.  Any piece of the plastic adjustable/moves?

Answer (score 3):

The metal slider looks like one side of a drawer slide.  The metal pin fits into the side of the drawer.  No idea about the plastic part.

Most IKEA parts are specialized to the configuration of the specific furniture you bought, and may be missing parts to make them more general.

Answer (score 0):

First guess

It is a sliding curtain rood for vertical blinds.

The plastic part gets mounted on the wall,or inside the window opening.

The rood snaps in to it.

[image: rood]

Comment: Seems too short for vertical blinds.  More of the length of a drawer slide, maybe one where the drawer clips in/on.